# simple onclick function on button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the class of a button when clicking on it. Why isn't mine working:
see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUmza/20/)

HTML:

```
<button id="repeatMon" onclick="changeStyle()"><span> Mon </span></button> 
<br/>
<button id="repeatTues" data-bind="checked: repeatTues" onclick="changeStyle()"><span> Tues </span></button> 
<br/>
<button id="repeatWeds" data-bind="checked: repeatWeds" onclick="changeStyle()"><span> Weds </span></button> 
<br/>
<button id="repeatThurs" data-bind="checked: repeatThurs" onclick="changeStyle()"><span> Thurs </span></button> 
<br/>
<button id="repeatFri" data-bind="checked: repeatFri" onclick="changeStyle()"><span> Fri </span></button> 
<br/>
<button id="repeatSat" data-bind="checked: repeatSat" onclick="changeStyle()"><span> Sat </span></button> 
<br/>
<button id="repeatSun" data-bind="checked: repeatSun" onclick="changeStyle()"><span> Sun </span></button> 
<br/>
```

CSS:

```
button{
    width: 60px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #cfcfcf;
    background: #0a4a58;
}

.active{
    color: #fff;
    background: ##02AEFF;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function changeStyle(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
}
```

thank you!

Comment: `onclick="changeStyle(this)"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using jquery so you don't have to repeat yourself. Remove `onclick` from button and do it with jquery

```
<button id="repeatMon"><span> Mon </span></button> <br/>
<button id="repeatTues" data-bind="checked: repeatTues"><span> Tues </span></button><br/>
<button id="repeatWeds" data-bind="checked: repeatWeds"><span> Weds </span></button><br/>
<button id="repeatThurs" data-bind="checked: repeatThurs"><span> Thurs </span></button><br/>
<button id="repeatFri" data-bind="checked: repeatFri"><span> Fri </span></button><br/>
<button id="repeatSat" data-bind="checked: repeatSat"><span> Sat </span></button><br/>
<button id="repeatSun" data-bind="checked: repeatSun"><span> Sun </span></button><br/>
```

remove the extra hash (#) from your color in css in class active

```
.active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #02AEFF;
}
```

and write the script

```
$(function() {
    var buttons = $('button[id^="repeat"]');
    buttons.click(function() {
        buttons.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7ehx/3/)

Answer (score 5):

You're using jQuery, remove the inline JS and do it the proper way :

```
$('[id^="repeat"]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VUmza/27/)

To toggle the active state on one button at the time :

```
$('[id^="repeat"]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: thank you. Appreciate. But what do I do if i only want to change one class at a time? ie only one button can have the toggled class?

Answer (score 4):

```
<button id="repeatSun" data-bind="checked: repeatSun" onclick="changeStyle(this)"><span> Sun </span></button> 

function changeStyle(btn){
    $(btn).toggleClass('active');
}
```

---

Alternatively a better method would be to add [click event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/click/) with your jQuery.

Add the same class to all your buttons and apply a click event handler to that class:

```
<button id="repeatSun" data-bind="checked: repeatSun" class="changestyle"><span> Sun </span></button>

$(".changestyle").click(function(){
   $(".changestyle").removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: `this` is reserved, I think.

Comment: @dystroy I was thinking that to be honest, but I wasn't certain. Have updated answer in case.

Comment: thank you for your answer. the first one does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/VUmza/33/

Comment: Second one works(thanks). However, If I only want to be able to change one class at a time (currently you can change more than one), how do I do it?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden I've updated my answer for only allowing 1 at a time. I'm not sure why your fiddle doesn't work though...

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the button.

```
function changeStyle(e){
    $(e).toggleClass('active');
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<button id="repeatSun" data-bind="checked: repeatSun" onclick="changeStyle(this)"><span> Sun </span></button>
```

Comment: @DavidVanStaden Where is the `onclick` on the button? You need to give `onclick="changeStyle(this)"`.

Comment: @DavidVanStaden That was a problem with jsfiddle. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/VUmza/42/ It works!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VUmza/26/

EDIT: Only one button at a time.

http://jsfiddle.net/VUmza/39/

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $( "button" ).each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    });

    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: thanks. it works. how do I enable only ONE button at a time to be able to toggle the class...

Comment: @DavidVanStaden I've edited my post to only toggle one at a time.

Comment: Thank you. It works great. Appreciate your answer, but unfortunately pbaris's answer is better

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<button id="repeatMon" class="clickable"><span> Mon </span></button>
```

Jquery inside document.ready()

```
$('.clickable').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rCZSN/)